# Communication between threads via delegates?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am looking for a solution for interthread communication. 
Thread A is the main thread of a windows app. I starts a Thread B that is working independant of thread a, they do not share code. But thread A has to get some feedback about status of thread b. I try to solve this with a delegate. 
I am very sorry, I forgot to add that I have to work on .net 3.5, c#, WEC7

It is important that the code

```
public void OnMyEvent(string foo)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(foo);
        }
```

is executed in context of thread a, how can I achieve this

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
//...
    public void StartThread(Object obj)
    {
        new ClassForSecondThread(obj as Parameters);            
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //ParameterizedThreadStart threadstart = new ParameterizedThreadStart(startThread);
        ParameterizedThreadStart threadstart = new ParameterizedThreadStart(StartThread);
        Thread thread = new Thread(threadstart);
        Parameters parameters = new Parameters(){MyEventHandler = OnMyEvent};
        thread.Start(parameters);                        
    }

    public void OnMyEvent(string foo)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(foo);
    }
}

//This code is executed in Thread B
public class ClassForSecondThread
{
    public ClassForSecondThread(Parameters parameters)
    {
        if (parameters == null) 
            return;
        MyEventhandler += parameters.MyEventHandler;
        DoWork();
    }

    private void DoWork()
    {
        //DoSomething
        if (MyEventhandler != null)
            MyEventhandler.DynamicInvoke("Hello World");// I think this should be executed async, in Thread A
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        if (MyEventhandler != null)
            MyEventhandler.DynamicInvoke("Hello World again"); // I think this should be executed async, in Thread A
    }

    public event MyEventHandler MyEventhandler;
}
public class Parameters
{
    public MyEventHandler MyEventHandler;
}

public delegate void MyEventHandler(string foo);
```

Comment: Your sample code is pretty relevant for the real problem with this kind of approach.  Nothing happens for 10 seconds so the user gave up and closed the window.  That won't end well.

Comment: Go take a look at the task parallel library http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx

Comment: @Hans Passant: but there is a way for the Main thread to know, there is still another thread running, isn't there? It is, in the next step important, to be able to call code in thread b two, to make the thread stop an external device and stop itself

Answer (score 2):

As you want to call the MessageBox on the main UI thread, you can achieve what you want using `Control.Invoke`.

```
     Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => MessageBox.Show(foo)));
```

The [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) method can be called directly on the Form and you won't be in the context of Thread B within the delegate - the code will run on the same thread as the Form.

EDIT:
OP question: if I understood Control.Invoke correctly, it always acts in the context of a control?

Although the Invoke method uses a Control (in this case the form) to get a handle to the UI thread it is running on, the code within the delegate is not specific to the UI. If you want to add more statements and expand it to include more stuff, just do this:

```
        string t = "hello"; //declared in the form

        //Thread B context - Invoke called
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => 
            {
                //Back to the UI thread of the Form here == thread A 
                MessageBox.Show(foo);
                t = "dd";
            }));
```

Also, if you are updating things in a multi threaded environment where the data is accessible to more than one thread, then you will need to investigate [sychronization](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx) - applying locks to data etc.

Comment: But that will show the message box in the context of thread A, the main Windows thread, and the OP stated that they wanted it to be shown in the context of thread B. Although I think maybe the OP isn't being very clear...

Comment: Sorry, I saw right now there was mistake, and I edited it, I meant thread a...  Right ow it is executed in context of thread b. Sorry

Comment: @Jaycee: thank you very much for your answer. Inthe real application, the code that will have to executed is in the UI Tread, but it is not just UIcode, and if I understood Control.Invoke correctly, it always acts in the context of a control

Comment: @traveller No problem. Will add a little extra detail

Comment: @jaycee: thank you very very much. Is it a problem, if the code in thread b is in a separate dll, and project, that contains code for "A" references project that contains code for b, but so "Project b" has no reference to project a?

Comment: @traveller The issue of threads is completely separate from how your code is organised. So long as you have access to the relevant code from your threads via references then it will work. Good luck!

Comment: @jaycee Thread b only knows the eventhandler, maybe I need to include a reference to the Form in the parameters?

Comment: @traveller It might be better to create a working example with 2 projects demonstrating what you would like to achieve and ask a new question

Comment: @jaycee I now build the solution with three projects... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607000/communication-between-threads-via-delegates-in-multi-tier-architecture  thank you very very much for all your help

Answer (score 1):

For what it is worth you can simplify your code considerably by using the new `async` and `await` keywords in C# 5.0.

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
  private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
  {
    OnMyEvent("Hello World");
    await Task.Run(
      () =>
      {
        // This stuff runs on a worker thread.
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
      });
    OnMyEvent("Hello World again");
  }

  private void OnMyEvent(string foo)
  {
    Message.Show(foo);
  }

}
```

In the code above `OnMyEvent` is executed on the UI thread in both cases. The first call be executed before the task starts and the second call will be executed after the task completes.