# Communication between threads via delegates in Multi Tier Architecture?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am looking for a solution for Interthread communication. 
We got a Three Tier Architecture,

Gui, 
  references
Logic
  references
Devicecontroller

Thread A is the main thread of a windows app. I starts a Thread B that is working independant of thread a, they do not share code. But thread A has to get some feedback about status of thread b. I try to solve this with a delegate. I have to work on .net 3.5, c#, WEC7

Gui and Logic run in context of Thread A
DeviceController runs in Context of Thread B. Both Threads are long running
Thread A starts and controls Thread B.
Thread A (Logic) gets information back from B (DeviceController) and updates the Gui or the database

It is important that the code is executed in Thread A

```
    public void OnMyEvent(string foo)
    {
        //there may be access to Gui here, there may be other actions, like accessing database
        // All this should be in context of thread A
        MessageBox.Show(foo);
    }

// The Gui
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    //This code is executed in Thread A, UIThread
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ThreadController threadController = new ThreadController();
            threadController.StartThread(this, e);
        }

    }

}

//Tier Logic, runs in Context of Thread A
namespace Logic
{
    //this class runs in the context of Thread A
    public  class ThreadController
    {
        public void StartThread(Object obj)
        {
            new ClassForSecondThread(obj as Parameters);
        }

        public void StartThread(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //ParameterizedThreadStart threadstart = new ParameterizedThreadStart(startThread);
            ParameterizedThreadStart threadstart = new ParameterizedThreadStart(StartThread);
            Thread thread = new Thread(threadstart);
            Parameters parameters = new Parameters() {MyEventHandler = OnMyEvent};
            thread.Start(parameters);
        }

        public void OnMyEvent(string foo)
        {
            //there may be access to Gui here, there may be other actions, like accessing database
            // All this should be in context of thread A. Here it is unfortunately in Context Thread B
            MessageBox.Show(foo);
        }
    }
}
```

//runs in context of Thread B
namespace DeviceController
{

```
//This class runs in the context of  Thread B
public class ClassForSecondThread
{
    public ClassForSecondThread(Parameters parameters)
    {
        if (parameters == null)
            return;
        MyEventhandler += parameters.MyEventHandler;
        DoWork();
    }

    private void DoWork()
    {
        //DoSomething
        if (MyEventhandler != null)
            MyEventhandler.DynamicInvoke("Hello World"); 
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        if (MyEventhandler != null)
            MyEventhandler.DynamicInvoke("Hello World again");

    }

    private event MyEventHandler MyEventhandler;
}

public class Parameters
{
    public MyEventHandler MyEventHandler;
}

public delegate void MyEventHandler(string foo);
```

}

There are two issues, I cannot yet handle:

No 1: OnMyEvent still runs in context of thread b
No 2: I need the same communication the other way, if there is some event in the gui, the devicecontroller has to be informed about e.g. shutdown etc.

Comment: Both your queried are related to SynchronizationContext. Have a look at this Code Project article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31971/Understanding-SynchronizationContext-Part-I. Btw, TPL makes it all a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the thread A is the GUI thread you could use Control.BeginInvoke to dispatch delegate calls to UI thread.

You just have to make an instance of your GUI control to be accessible from your thread B. Then you can call BeginInvoke on it as long as that control is Visible.

To communicate with device controller you will probably have to create a synchronized queue.

[SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) class in .Net provide the basis for this and has an implementation that will work for dispatching from other thread to UI thread. But to make it work the other way around you may have to write your own implementation.

Comment: it willnot be possible, to use a delegate this way too like the way from UIThread to Thread B?

Comment: I have just felt the pain that Wec7 does not support ParameterizedThreadStart. Anybody idea what to do instead, to make this run on WEC7?

Comment: @traveller of course it is not possible directly. SynchronizationContext  only support dispatching things to UIThread only. To do it the other way you have to write your own dispatch queue which will be polled from Thread B.